# Python Scrapy: What is the difference between item._values and item.fields?

Tags: python, scrapy

(Using Scrapy 1.0.0): I have declared an item with three fields:

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here                                                                 
    correct_ans = scrapy.Field()
    pronunciation = scrapy.Field()
    good_alts = scrapy.Field()

def __init__(self, correct_ans, pronunciation):
    # bad style??                                                                                      
    super(MyItem, self).__init__()
    self._values['correct_ans'] = correct_ans
    self._values['pronunciation'] = pronunciation
    self._values['good_alts'] = []
```

Weirdly, after I instantiate a new MyItem, self._values and self.fields have different keys (see pdb output below). The question is ... why? Is this by design?

```
(Pdb) l
 24         def parse(self, response):
 25             for vocab in self.vocabs:
 26                 item = MyItem(vocab['correct_ans'], vocab['pronunciation'])
 27                 pdb.set_trace()
 28  ->             request = FormRequest.from_response(response, formnumber=1, 
 29                                                     formdata = {'word': item['pronunciation']}, 
 30                                                     callback =     self.parse_pinyin_match_page)
 31                 logging.debug("OK:" + str(request))
 32                 request.meta['item'] = item
 33                 yield request
(Pdb) item.fields
{'correct_ans': {}, 'pronunciation': {}}
(Pdb) item._values
{'correct_ans': '\xe9\x99\x88\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe4\xb8\x9c', 'pronunciation': 'chendadong', 'good_alts': []}
(Pdb) 'good_alts' in item.fields
False
(Pdb) 'good_alts' in item._values
True
(Pdb)
```

I hadn't had a problem with it until I tried to use the built-in CSV exporter. Now scrapy exits with the following error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 188, in export_item
    values = [x[1] for x in fields]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 72, in _get_serialized_fields
    field = {} if isinstance(item, dict) else item.fields[field_name]
KeyError: 'good_alts'
```

Comment: which version of scrapy are u using?

Comment: typing "scrapy version" gets me the response "Scrapy 1.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

I had also defined a function:

```
def good_alts():
    return self._values['good_alts']
```

Removing this function fixed the problem. So there was some sort of name conflict. Still a hugely befuddling error, but I should have known better than to use the same name for a function and an attribute.